Why is the address pool range represented and how is it located in the 209.165.201.0/27 subnet?
Why is the address pool range represented by
ip nat pool CISCO 209.165.201.1 209.165.201.30 netmask 255.255.255.224

209.165.201.1 to 209.165.201.30, and how is it located in the 209.165.201.0/27 subnet?

This Q&A might enlighten you: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C41.5336

The subnet mask 255.255.255.224 in this command corresponds to /27, which means that the subnet has 32 IP addresses. Here is the specific calculation process:
The /27 subnet mask means that the first 27 bits are network bits and the remaining 5 bits are used for host bits.
2^5 = 32, which means that the subnet can accommodate 32 IP addresses.
The IP range of 209.165.201.0/27 starts from 209.165.201.0 and goes to 209.165.201.31.
209.165.201.0 is the network address, and 209.165.201.31 is a broadcast address and cannot be used for hosts.
Therefore, the address range that can be used for hosts is 209.165.201.1 to 209.165.201.30.
In summary, ip nat pool CISCO 209.165.201.1 209.165.201.30 defines a NAT address pool of 30 available IP addresses, which is exactly in the 209.165.201.0/27 subnet.
